# Integration odoo 9.0 with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, integration, odoo, odoo-9

867/5000
Hello everyone!

I have a problem, in the place where I work they want me to create a login screen for the CRM so that the client, just enter their e-mail and password, and go directly to their CRM (without having to choose between all the databases ). The question is that you create a database and a login with php, clients at the beginning of the session ask all the data to the database so that it is directly connected with odoo.

When I bring all the data, I will put them in the corresponding field so that I send them to odoo (Work with odoo 9.0 and Ripcord). How can I establish that connection with odoo and that when it is successful, it redirects me to the client's CRM and leaves the login screen that believes it is hosted on a server?

I hope to have explained myself well, anything explained back. Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards!

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');

$url = $ODOO_URL;  //ODOO  Server Url
$db = $user['codigo'];                  //Database Name
$username = $user['usuario'];           //UserName
$password = $user['password_odoo'];     //Password

$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");

//Authenticate the credentials
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

//Create Model Instance
$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");

// Fetch the data by calling appropriate methods
$partner_field = array();
$partner_field=$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
                       'res.partner', 'fields_get',array(),
                        array('attributes' => array('string', 'help', 
'type')));
 ?>
```

What I try to do is that when I verify that the user's data is correct, I redirect to the odoo page with the customer's CRM open.

Comment: Hi Martin, I would try to post some code examples of what you have so far, and where you are getting stuck. SO will not write full fledged workflows for you, but is rather for detailed questions that show you have already done some research. Hope that helps!

Comment: Already! :D - thanks for the advice.